# No results in Sonarqube from SonarLint analysis and connected Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have configured IntelliJ with SonarLint to a connected SonarQube instance in AWS. I am able to run a code analysis in IntelliJ and I do get results back in IntelliJ.

But I want to have these results in Sonarqube. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on the documentation to see how to :

- Install SonarQube : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server
- Execute an analysis : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN

Comment: Installation is not an issue, it is running and I can access SonarQube. Analysis is done via IntelliJ. Can you point me where to look to get the analysis results in SonarQube?

Comment: The SonarLint plugins to not push analysis to SonarQube. To do that you need to setup a build job and use the corresponding Scanner, hence Julien suggested the second link.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation, then come back with some more detailed question

Answer (score 0):

If you have Jenkins you should have 2 jobs: one to build application from branch, another to run SonarQube analysis based on artifacts created by first job (build job). You can create a pipeline: when you push to git (or other repository) first job automatically will be started, when build is done and it’s successful it will trigger job to analyze code in sonar. Try to find configuration examples at https://docs.sonar.org/ or I can send you tomorrow details how we configured our pipeline. P.S. forgot to mention that you need to install SonarQube plugin in Jenkins too.

SonarLint: this tool only open connection to your Sonar server just to get rules for analysis, but analysis is done on your side (localhost) without sending results to Sonar server back. This is how SonarLint works.